# SQL Dependency query - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My main goal is to see which stored procedures that built up the said table as well as which views that is built on the table.

(I will export this to Power BI later to be able to filter on one table, and see the dependencies, but that is not the important part).

I have found from another Stackoverflow post a version that will do a part of the trick, by using the `sys.objects` and `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`. I have posted the query and output below.

The main problem is that I don't find a clear way to see which way the dependencies are going, without the indented names.

- Object Path is: `/_LoadV_CustomerToCustomer/Customer/dimDate`
- Level is: 2
- Object_type is:  USER_TABLE
- Base_Object_Name is:  `_Loadv_CustomerToCustomer`
- Object_ID is: data.Date

In this particular example one can see that the table `data.Date` is the only one that have Stored Procedure as base object type and level 2, but for other tables this is not true, so one cannot hardcode it that way.

Do anyone know any way to change the query or other way to find out in an easier way how the dependencies between the SQL tables, stored procedures and views are related?

Here is the query I have at the moment:

```
WITH ObjectHierarchy (Base_Object_Id , Base_Cchema_Id , Base_Object_Name , Base_Object_Type, object_id , Schema_Id , Name , Type_Desc , Level , Obj_Path) AS 
( 
    SELECT  
        so.object_id AS Base_Object_Id,
        so.schema_id AS Base_Cchema_Id,
        so.name AS Base_Object_Name, 
        so.type_desc AS Base_Object_Type,
        so.object_id AS object_id, 
        so.schema_id AS Schema_Id, 
        so.name,
        so.type_desc, 
        0 AS Level,
        CONVERT ( NVARCHAR ( 1000 ) , N'/' + so.name ) AS Obj_Path 
    FROM 
        sys.objects so 
    LEFT JOIN 
        sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed ON ed.referenced_id = so.object_id 
    LEFT JOIN 
        sys.objects rso ON rso.object_id = ed.referencing_id 
    WHERE 
        rso.type IS NULL 
        AND so.type IN ( 'P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF' ) 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT   
        cp.Base_Object_Id AS Base_Object_Id 
        , cp.Base_Cchema_Id 
        , cp.Base_Object_Name 
        , cp.Base_Object_Type
        , so.object_id AS object_id 
        , so.schema_id AS ID_Schema 
        , so.name 
        , so.type_desc 
        , Level + 1 AS Level 
        , CONVERT ( NVARCHAR ( 1000 ) , cp.Obj_Path + N'/' + so.name ) AS Obj_Path 
    FROM 
        sys.objects so 
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed ON ed.referenced_id = so.object_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.objects rso ON rso.object_id = ed.referencing_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        ObjectHierarchy AS cp ON rso.object_id = cp.object_id AND rso.object_id <> so.object_id 
    WHERE 
        so.type IN ('P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF', 'U') 
        AND (rso.type IS NULL OR rso.type IN ('P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF', 'U')) 
        AND cp.Obj_Path NOT LIKE '%/' + so.name + '/%'    -- prevent cycles n hierarchy
)
SELECT   
    Base_Object_Name 
    , Base_Object_Type
    , REPLICATE ( '   ' , Level ) + Name AS Indented_Name 
    , SCHEMA_NAME ( Schema_Id ) + '.' + Name AS object_id 
    , Type_Desc AS Object_Type 
    , Level 
    , Obj_Path 
FROM 
    ObjectHierarchy AS p 
ORDER BY 
    Obj_Path
```

Here is the output at the moment for Date example:

| Base_Object_Name | Base_Object_Type | object_id | obj_Path | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Load Customer | Stored Procedure | Date | /Load Customer/Customer/Date | 2 |
| Load Sales | Stored Procedure | Date | /Load Sales/Sales/Date | 2 |
| Load Products | Stored Procedure | Date | /Load Products/Products/Date | 2 |
| Load Date | Stored Procedure | Date | /Load Date/Date | 1 |
| Customer Support | VIEW | Date | /Customer Support/Cases/Date | 2 |
| Cases | VIEW | Date | /Cases/Date | 1 |

- Here I could find stored procedures by filter on "Level = 1".

But if we look at a similar one for Employee:

| Base_Object_Name | Base_Object_Type | object_id | obj_Path | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Run After Sync | Stored Procedure | Employee | /Run After Sync/Insert Employee/Employee | 2 |
| Filter Employee | Stored Procedure | Employee | /Filter Employee/Employee View/Employee | 4 |

- I can not filter on Level = 1, as there are two stored procedures that builds up employee.

My expected Output should be something like this, no matter what I filter.

Expected Output:

| Base_Object_Name | Base_Object_Type | object_id | obj_Path | Level | Original_Stored_Procedure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Load Customer | Stored Procedure | Date | /Load Customer/Customer/Date | 2 | No |
| Load Date | Stored Procedure | Date | /Load Date/Date | 1 | Yes |
| Run After Sync | Stored Procedure | Employee | /Run After Sync/Insert Employee/Employee | 2 | Yes |
| Filter Employee | Stored Procedure | Employee | /Filter Employee/Employee View/Employee | 4 | No |

The thing I want to find out is if there any possibility to add this column, so that I can always find what the original stored procedure is for any specific table.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am using SQL Server

Comment: Please, no pictures, use plain text in questions. What is the expected output?

Comment: Added tables with Expected Output, as well as plain text instead of Pictures.
Thanks for the remark.